# Recreating Photoshop Camera Raw texture slider using shader nodes

Tags: materials, shader-nodes

The texture slider in camera raw is great for aging/de-aging skin. It would be great we could do this procedurally using shader nodes inside blender. Is there a way to recreate this effect using nodes?

Original image:
[image]

Texture filter applied:
[image]

Comment: Hello, could you add a screenshot of the desired effect ?

Comment: I've added some images

Comment: Hi :). Adobe's "Texture slider" is a "smart" adjustment that combines midtone contrast + blur + some hidden adobe wizardry. If you figure out how exactly it works, it sure could be attempted with nodes :))